# Inquiry Symbols in Latex

Tags: symbols

Is there any package that we can use with the below symbols?

[image]

[image]

It is for the purpose of creating an inquiry form.

Thank you in advance.

Kind regards.

Comment: Also look at http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created two MWE with TikZ, if you prefer.

For the circle.
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[lightgray,fill=gray!10] (0,0) circle (0.4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For the rectangle. [image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[lightgray,fill=gray!10, rounded corners=5pt] (2,0) rectangle ++(1,1); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well done! Upvoted :)

Answer (score 4):

I propose something minimal with `fontawesome`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
\faCircleO{}

\faSquareO{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Those are in fact simple. But is there any symbol that can stand a bit off? This is, that has some bezel/shadow to it, so it can give it a little bit 3D shape?

Comment: @Focha not that I know about. You could embed an image I guess, to obtain exactly the result you need (I think it's the best choice). Typographically I feel the "simple" one are the best: the other ones seems more like a browser-dependent rendering of an html page rather than something that needs to be printed, since I feel they're gonna look not that good once printed.

Comment: I wonder why fontawesome uses such different line weights.  The circle looks a little heavy for most text

Comment: @ChrisH that's what I thought too